# Symfony : Unable to find the socket transport "http"

Tags: php, symfony, debian

I'm trying to learn Symfony. So I've downloaded the installer from [symfony.com](https://symfony.com/download).

My `http_proxy` / `https_proxy` are defined, and my DNS too. Unless, the command `sudo curl -LsS https://symfony.com/installer -o /usr/local/bin/symfony` used to download the installer could not work.

Now, I want to create a new project, so in my project folder I type `symfony new project`. Same thing if I specify `symfony new project 2.8` or `symfony new project 3.0`.

The result is an error message :

```
 Downloading Symfony...

  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_latest.tgz): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "http" -
   did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 407

  [GuzzleHttp\Ring\Exception\RingException]
  Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://symfony.com/download?v=Symfony_Standard_Vendors_latest.tgz): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "http" -
   did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 406
  [message] Undefined variable: http_response_header
  [file] phar:///usr/local/bin/symfony/vendor/guzzlehttp/ringphp/src/Client/StreamHandler.php
  [line] 407

new <directory> [<version>]
```

If I do a `phpinfo()`, I've openssl :

```
openssl
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
Openssl default config  /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

My PHP version if I do a `php -v` :

```
PHP 5.6.17-0+deb8u1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2016 09:10:12)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2015, by Zend Technologies
```

My question : Why is there an error when I try to create a new  project and how to fix it ? Is it due to PHP version ? Do I need a linux package or an other PHP extension ? Is there anything else to configure somewhere ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Arf -_-'

Ok, I've been blocked half a day yesterday on this point. That'why I decided to ask on StackOverflow... And Finally I just found the answer ...

[git-hub Symfony-installer issues](https://github.com/symfony/symfony-installer/issues/124)

I had to install `php5-curl`.

`apt-get install php5-curl`

Hope it could at least help someone in the future.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I'm using laravel behind a proxy server.