# Setting up a new Laravel site behind a company proxy

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, proxy, guzzle

We've recently spun up a new Linux (Ubuntu 16.04) server at work as a web server, and I've been trying to set up a new Laravel site for a project. After some initial trouble setting up the server with the work proxy, we eventually sorted it and all traffic seems to route correctly (we used [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175172/how-do-i-configure-proxies-without-gui)).

However, when I'm trying to set up a new Laravel site with `laravel new`, I get this back:

> `[RuntimeException]
>     Error creating resource: [message] fopen(http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip): failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket transport "http" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?
>     [file] /home/user/.config/composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/StreamHandler.php
>     [line] 324`

Now, I figure this is something to do with fopen and the proxy, and I've tried a couple of things, first [this](http://john.cuppi.net/proxy-outgoing-connections-via-php/), and then setting the proxy in RequestOptions.php in Guzzle, but I can't get it to work. Am I looking at this the right way, or am I completely wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony : Unable to find the socket transport "http"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35912524/symfony-unable-to-find-the-socket-transport-http)

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to install cURL extension for PHP. Something like `apt-get install php7-curl`, depends on your OS. Then Guzzle will use cURL instead of PHP's integrated stream wrappers.

Or enable HTTP support for streams in PHP by reinstalling it. Somehow you don't have [`http` wrapper installed](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php).